# Sometimes image reduction does not work

Tags: powershell

I have a script which reduces image but I just noticed that some photo are enlarged. For exemple I have a photo with size 808 Ko, after execution of my script, the size of image is 1520 Ko.

Why some photos are enlarged and not others ?

Here my script :

```
$source = "P:\PAULINE DF informatique\Communication\*.jpg"
$exclude_list = "(LOGOS ET DIVERS SUPPORT|!CARTES DE VOEUX 2017|LOGO)"
$scale = 2.2

$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_list}

$log = "U:\TEST\Photos - test\log_photo_2.txt"

foreach ( $source_photos in $source_listephotos ) {

$log_image = Get-Content "U:\TEST\Photos - test\log_photo_2.txt"

for ( $a = 1; $a -lt 100; $a++ ) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Working ..." -PercentComplete $a -CurrentOperation "$a% complete" -Status "Please Wait."
    }

    if ($log_image -eq $source_photos) {Write-Host OK}
        else {
            $source = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($source_photos.FullName)
            $size = "$([int]($source.Width/$scale)), $([int]($source.Height/$scale))"
            $dest = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($source, $size)
            $source.Dispose()
            $dest.Save($source_photos.Fullname)
            $dest.Dispose()
        }

     if($? -eq $false){echo "$source_photos pas compressé" | out-file -append $log} 
          else 
              {echo "$source_photos" | out-file -append $log}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, as the file is saved by default in PNG format. However, the file extension doesn't change, so it's hard to tell the difference. This can be verified by opening the file in hex editor and cheking the header for PNG magic bytes `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`. A JPG header begins with `ff d8 ff`.

JPG is a lossy format and compresses photos quite nicely. PNG is lossless and can't utilize the same tricks for reducing file size as JPG does. Thus converting from JPG to PNG tends to increase file size. Not always though, somes images are highly compressible in PNG format too.

As a solution, [save the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx) in JPG format like so,

```
$dest.Save("C:\path-to-file", [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg)
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explication, I have understand. I try the solution, however in "c:\path-to-file" I have put "$source". Thanks you again